# Failed Octave Uninstallation on Ubuntu 12.04 (Trouble Reinstalling Octave)

Tags: software-installation, software-uninstall, octave

I'm an Ubuntu *newb*, so please bear with me.

On trying to uninstall octave-3.2.4, I ended up doing **rm -rf** on all the octave related directories and files in **/usr/bin/** before I could install the latest version of GNU Octave. On trying to install Octave now, I'm getting the following error, with which I need help resolving:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
octave : 

Depends: libarpack2 (>= 2.1) but it is not going to be installed  
      Depends: libfftw3-3 but it is not installable  
      Depends: liboctave3 (= 4.0.0-3ubuntu2~octave~precise5) but it is   not going to be installed  
      Depends: libqscintilla2-8 but it is not installable  
      Depends: default-jre-headless but it is not installable  
      Recommends: pstoedit but it is not installable  
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**My commands attempting to reinstall Octave:**

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-3.8.0.tar.bz2
tar -xvf octave-3.8.0.tar.bz2
cd octave-3.8.0
sudo apt-get build-dep octave
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

**Edit:** Output of `apt-cache policy libarpack2`

```
libarpack2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.0.2-3
  Version table:
     3.0.2-3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**Edit:** Output of `apt-cache policy libarpack2-dev`

```
libarpack2-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.0.2-3
  Version table:
     3.0.2-3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe amd64 Packages
```

**Edit:** I hope this is relevant for a clue. Output for `sudo apt-get upgrade`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  dpkg-dev libatlas3gf-base libblas-dev libblas3gf libdpkg-perl liblapack-dev liblapack3gf linux-headers-generic-lts-quantal
  linux-image-generic-lts-quantal r-base-dev r8168-dkms texinfo
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
```

**Edit:** Output of `apt-cache policy libarpack2 libfftw3-3 liboctave3 libqscintilla2-8 default-jre-headless pstoedit`

```
libarpack2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.0.2-3
  Version table:
     3.0.2-3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libfftw3-3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     3.3-1ubuntu1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
liboctave3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.0.0-3ubuntu2~octave~precise5
  Version table:
     4.0.0-3ubuntu2~octave~precise5 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/octave/stable/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
libqscintilla2-8:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
default-jre-headless:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
pstoedit:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

**Edit:** Output of `sudo apt-get install libarpack2 libfftw3-3 liboctave3 libqscintilla2-8 default-jre-headless pstoedit`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libfftw3-3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package default-jre-headless is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package pstoedit is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libqscintilla2-8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libfftw3-3' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libqscintilla2-8' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'default-jre-headless' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'pstoedit' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Made an edit to provide the commands attempting reinstallation

Comment: I recommend you to run `sudo apt-get build-dep octave` in terminal to solve dependencies issue. Then install as you mentioned in question.

Comment: I tried that. I get this:  
E: Build-Depends dependency for octave cannot be satisfied because the package libqscintilla2-dev cannot be found

Comment: edit Q and add output of `apt-cache policy libarpack2`  and `apt-cache policy libarpack2-dev` @Anirudh

Comment: I wonder whats wrong with installing `libqscintilla2-dev` by `sudo apt-get install libqscintilla2-dev` @Ravan @Anirudh

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libarpack2 libfftw3-3 liboctave3 libqscintilla2-8 default-jre-headless pstoedit`

Comment: And the output of `sudo apt-get install libarpack2 libfftw3-3 liboctave3 libqscintilla2-8 default-jre-headless pstoedit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All missing packages are in the main repository, therfore

```
sudo apt-add-repository main
sudo apt-get update
```

And `multiverse` is also a good idea

```
sudo apt-add-repository multiverse
sudo apt-get update
```

If `sudo apt-add-repository main` and `sudo apt-add-repository multiverse` doesn't work, do the following

1. `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak`
2. Open <kbd>Software & Updates</kbd>
3. Activate the entries for `main`, `universe` and `multiverse`

   [image]
4. Click <kbd>Close</kbd>
5. Refresh the package sources via <kbd>Reload</kbd>

   [image]

---

*Remove your self-compiling adventure*

```
cd octave-3.8.0
sudo make uninstall
```

---

*Install `octave` again via*

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall octave
```

---

**And please, don't "remove" packages via deleting files in `/usr/bin`**

Comment: I get the following for main and multiverse:  `Error: 'main' invalid` and `Error: 'multiverse' invalid`

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: You're brilliant! Thanks for walking me through the fix step-by-step. Cheers! And your warning in bold duly noted. :)