# Could not install GNU Octave

Tags: 14.04, apt, dependencies, octave

I am getting below error while installing ocatve.

Command I run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install octave
```

Error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

octave: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
        Depends: libglpk36 (>= 4.51) but 4.52.1-2build1 is to be installed
        Depends: liboctave2 (= 3.8.1-1ubuntu1) but 3.8.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
        Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
        Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
        Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
        Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1 is to be installed
        Depends: octave-common (= 3.8.1-1ubuntu1) but 3.8.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

I have already tried solution at this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/685815/failed-octave-uninstallation-on-ubuntu-12-04-trouble-reinstalling-octave) but it did not worked for me.

I am naive to ubuntu and clueless what should I try next.

> EDIT

Command 1 : sudo apt-get install octave

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 octave : Depends: libarpack2 (>= 2.1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libcholmod2.1.2 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: liboctave2 (= 3.8.1-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: libatlas3-base but it is not going to be installed or
                      libopenblas-base but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Command 2 : apt search octave

```
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
amsynth/trusty 1.3.2-2 amd64
  two oscillator software synthesizer

cantor/trusty 4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1 amd64
  interface for mathematical applications

cantor-backend-octave/trusty 4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1 amd64
  Octave backend for Cantor

cauchy-dev/trusty 0.9.0-0ubuntu1 amd64
  library for transforming Matlab/Octave files to C++

cauchy-tools/trusty 0.9.0-0ubuntu1 amd64
  library for transforming Matlab/Octave files to C++ - toold

dynare/trusty 4.4.1-1build1 amd64
  platform for handling a wide class of economic models

dynare-common/trusty 4.4.1-1build1 all
  platform for handling a wide class of economic models (common files)

fomp/trusty 1.0.0~dfsg0-1 amd64
  collection of LV2 audio plugins

h5utils/trusty 1.12.1-2 amd64
  HDF5 files visualization tools

jack-keyboard/trusty 2.7.1-1 amd64
  Virtual MIDI keyboard for JACK MIDI

libaudiomask-dev/trusty 1.0-2ubuntu1 amd64
  Audio masking threshold estimation lib headers, docs and examples

libcauchy0.0/trusty 0.9.0-0ubuntu1 amd64
  library for transforming Matlab/Octave files to C++

libcauchyxunit0.0/trusty 0.9.0-0ubuntu1 amd64
  library for transforming Matlab/Octave files to C++

libfann-dbg/trusty 2.1.0~beta~dfsg-8ubuntu1 amd64
  Debugging symbols for FANN

libfann-dev/trusty 2.1.0~beta~dfsg-8ubuntu1 amd64
  Development libraries and header files for FANN

libfann-doc/trusty 2.1.0~beta~dfsg-8ubuntu1 all
  API documentation for FANN

libfann2/trusty 2.1.0~beta~dfsg-8ubuntu1 amd64
  Fast Artificial Neural Network Library

libitpp-dev/trusty 4.3.1-2 amd64
  C++ library of signal processing and communication routines: Headers

libitpp-doc/trusty 4.3.1-2 all
  C++ library of signal processing and communication routines: Documentation

libitpp8/trusty 4.3.1-2 amd64
  C++ library of signal processing and communication routines

libitpp8-dbg/trusty 4.3.1-2 amd64
  C++ library of signal processing and communication routines: Debug symbols

libm2mml0.0/trusty 0.9.0-0ubuntu1 amd64
  library for transforming Matlab/Octave files to C++

libmgl-data/trusty 2.1.3.1-4ubuntu3 all
  library for scientific graphs (data files)

libmgl-dev/trusty 2.1.3.1-4ubuntu3 amd64
  library for scientific graphs (development files)

libmgl-fltk7.0.0/trusty 2.1.3.1-4ubuntu3 amd64
  library for scientific graphs (fltk interface for windows)

libmgl-glut7.0.0/trusty 2.1.3.1-4ubuntu3 amd64
  library for scientific graphs (glut interface for windows)

libmgl-mpi7.0.0/trusty 2.1.3.1-4ubuntu3 amd64
  library for scientific graphs (mpi enhanced runtime library)

libmgl-qt7.0.0/trusty 2.1.3.1-4ubuntu3 amd64
  library for scientific graphs (Qt interface for windows)

libmgl-wnd7.0.0/trusty 2.1.3.1-4ubuntu3 amd64
  library for scientific graphs (windows runtime library)

libmgl-wx7.0.0/trusty 2.1.3.1-4ubuntu3 amd64
  library for scientific graphs (wx interface for windows)

libmgl7.0.0/trusty 2.1.3.1-4ubuntu3 amd64
  library for scientific graphs (main runtime library)

libnlopt-dev/trusty 2.4.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1 amd64
  nonlinear optimization library -- development package

libnlopt-guile0/trusty 2.4.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1 amd64
  nonlinear optimization library -- Guile bindings

libnlopt0/trusty 2.4.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1 amd64
  nonlinear optimization library

liboctave-dev/trusty 3.8.1-1ubuntu1 amd64
  Development files for the GNU Octave language

liboctave2/trusty 3.8.1-1ubuntu1 amd64
  Shared libraries of the GNU Octave language

libplplot-dev/trusty 5.10.0-0ubuntu5 amd64
  Scientific plotting library (development files)

libqrupdate-dev/trusty 1.1.1-1 amd64
  Fast updates of QR and Cholesky decompositions -- static library

libqrupdate1/trusty 1.1.1-1 amd64
  Fast updates of QR and Cholesky decompositions

libsbsms-dev/trusty 2.0.1-1 amd64
  Subband Sinusoidal Modeling Synthesis (development files)

libsbsms10/trusty 2.0.1-1 amd64
  Subband Sinusoidal Modeling Synthesis

libshogun-dbg/trusty 3.1.1-1 amd64
  Large Scale Machine Learning Toolbox

libshogun-dev/trusty 3.1.1-1 amd64
  Large Scale Machine Learning Toolbox

libshogun15/trusty 3.1.1-1 amd64
  Large Scale Machine Learning Toolbox

libsox-fmt-base/trusty 14.4.1-3ubuntu1 amd64
  Minimal set of SoX format libraries

libvlfeat-dev/trusty 0.9.17+dfsg0-6build1 amd64
  Computer vision library focussing on visual features and clustering

libvlfeat-doc/trusty 0.9.17+dfsg0-6build1 all
  Computer vision library focussing on visual features and clustering

libvlfeat0/trusty 0.9.17+dfsg0-6build1 amd64
  Computer vision library focussing on visual features and clustering

libvlfeat0-dbg/trusty 0.9.17+dfsg0-6build1 amd64
  Computer vision library focussing on visual features and clustering

mathgl/trusty 2.1.3.1-4ubuntu3 amd64
  library for scientific graphs (utilities and examples)

mathgl-doc-en/trusty 2.1.3.1-4ubuntu3 all
  library for scientific graphs (English documentation)

matlab-support-dev/trusty 0.0.19 all
  helpers for packages building MATLAB toolboxes

matlab2tikz/trusty 0.4.4-1 all
  converter of Octave plots to TikZ figures (for integration into LaTeX)

mwrap/trusty 0.33-1 amd64
  Octave/MATLAB mex generator

octave/trusty 3.8.1-1ubuntu1 amd64
  GNU Octave language for numerical computations

octave-audio/trusty 1.1.4-4build1 amd64
  functions to work with audio files in Octave

octave-benchmark/trusty 1.1.1-4 all
  code to benchmark speed of Octave

octave-bim/trusty 1.1.3-1 all
  PDE solver using a finite element/volume approach in Octave

octave-biosig/trusty 1.3.0-2build2 amd64
  Octave bindings for BioSig library

octave-common/trusty 3.8.1-1ubuntu1 all
  architecture-independent files for octave

octave-communications/trusty 1.2.0-1build1 amd64
  communications package for Octave

octave-communications-common/trusty 1.2.0-1build1 all
  communications package for Octave (arch-indep files)

octave-control/trusty 2.6.2-1build1 amd64
  control functions for Octave from Octave-Forge

octave-data-smoothing/trusty 1.3.0-2 all
  functions to do data smoothing on noisy data

octave-dataframe/trusty 0.9.1-1 all
  manipulate data in Octave similar to R data.frame

octave-dbg/trusty 3.8.1-1ubuntu1 amd64
  Debug symbols for octave

octave-doc/trusty 3.8.1-1ubuntu1 all
  PDF documentation on the GNU Octave language

octave-econometrics/trusty 1:1.1.1-2build1 amd64
  econometrics functions for Octave

octave-epstk/trusty 2.4-1 all
  GNU Octave encapsulated postscript toolkit

octave-financial/trusty 0.4.0-1 all
  financial manipulation and plotting functions

octave-fpl/trusty 1.3.4-1 all
  plot data on unstructured triangular and tetrahedral meshes in Octave

octave-ga/trusty 0.10.0-1 all
  genetic optimization code for Octave

octave-gdf/trusty 0.1.2-2build3 amd64
  IO library for the GDF -- Octave interface

octave-general/trusty 1.3.4-1 amd64
  provide extra general functions for Octave

octave-geometry/trusty 1.7.0-1build1 amd64
  geometric computing functions for Octave

octave-gmt/trusty 4.5.11-1build1 amd64
  Support of GMT grid files for Octave

octave-gsl/trusty 1.0.8-5build1 amd64
  GSL binding for Octave

octave-htmldoc/trusty 3.8.1-1ubuntu1 all
  HTML documentation on the GNU Octave language

octave-image/trusty 2.2.0-3 amd64
  image manipulation for Octave

octave-info/trusty 3.8.1-1ubuntu1 all
  GNU Info documentation on the GNU Octave language

octave-io/trusty 2.0.2-1ubuntu1 amd64
  input/output data functions for Octave

octave-lhapdf/trusty 5.9.1-3build1 amd64
  Octave Bindings for LHAPDF

octave-linear-algebra/trusty 2.2.0-1build1 amd64
  additional linear-algebra functions for Octave

octave-mapping/trusty 1.0.7-4 all
  geographical mapping functions for Octave

octave-miscellaneous/trusty 1.2.0-2build1 amd64
  miscellaneous tools for Octave

octave-missing-functions/trusty 1.0.2-4 all
  finds functions that are in Matlab but not in Octave

octave-mpi/trusty 1.1.1-1build2 amd64
  Octave toolbox for parallel computing using MPI

octave-msh/trusty 1.0.6-1 all
  create and manage meshes for FE or FV solvers in Octave

octave-nan/trusty 2.5.9-1build1 amd64
  handles data with and without missing values in Octave

octave-nlopt/trusty 2.4.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1 amd64
  nonlinear optimization library -- GNU Octave package

octave-nnet/trusty 0.1.13-2 all
  feed forward multi-layer neural network functions for Octave

octave-nurbs/trusty 1.3.7-1build1 amd64
  non-uniform rational B-splines for Octave

octave-ocs/trusty 0.1.3-1build1 amd64
  circuit simulator for Octave

octave-octcdf/trusty 1.1.7-1 amd64
  NetCDF data files interface for Octave

octave-octgpr/trusty 1.2.0-3build1 amd64
  functions to smooth and interpolate scattered data in Octave

octave-odepkg/trusty 0.8.4-1build1 amd64
  solve differential equations and initial value problems in Octave

octave-openmpi-ext/trusty 1.1.1-1build2 all
  Transitional package for parallel computing in Octave using MPI

octave-optim/trusty 1.3.0-1 amd64
  unconstrained non-linear optimization toolkit for Octave

octave-optiminterp/trusty 0.3.4-1build1 amd64
  optimal interpolation package for Octave

octave-parallel/trusty 2.2.0-1build1 amd64
  parallel execution of Octave in clusters of computers

octave-pfstools/trusty 1.8.5-1ubuntu3 amd64
  octave bindings for pfstools

octave-pkg-dev/trusty 1.1.1 all
  infrastructure to build Octave packages

octave-plot/trusty 1.1.0-2 all
  additional plotting tools for Octave

octave-psychtoolbox-3/trusty 3.0.11.20131230.dfsg1-1build1 amd64
  toolbox for vision research -- Octave bindings

octave-quaternion/trusty 2.2.0-1build1 amd64
  quaternion package for Octave

octave-secs1d/trusty 0.0.9-2 all
  semi conductor simulator in 1D for Octave

octave-secs2d/trusty 0.0.8-4build1 amd64
  semi conductor simulator in 2D for Octave

octave-signal/trusty 1.2.2-1build1 amd64
  signal processing functions for Octave

octave-sockets/trusty 1.0.8-1build1 amd64
  communication through Internet sockets in Octave

octave-specfun/trusty 1.1.0-1build1 amd64
  special mathematical functions for Octave

octave-splines/trusty 1.2.6-1 all
  cubic spline functions for Octave

octave-statistics/trusty 1.2.3-1 all
  additional statistical functions for Octave

octave-strings/trusty 1.1.0-1build1 amd64
  additional string manipulation functions for Octave

octave-struct/trusty 1.0.10-1build1 amd64
  additional structure manipulation functions for Octave

octave-sundials/trusty 2.5.0-3ubuntu1 amd64
  SUNDIALS  for octave

octave-symbolic/trusty 1.1.0-2build1 amd64
  symbolic package for Octave

octave-tsa/trusty 4.2.7-1build1 amd64
  time series analysis in Octave

octave-vlfeat/trusty 0.9.17+dfsg0-6build1 amd64
  Computer vision library focussing on visual features and clustering

octave-vrml/trusty 1.0.13-1 all
  VRML functions for Octave

octave-zenity/trusty 0.5.7-5 all
  simple graphical user interfaces using zenity in Octave

pd-iemmatrix/trusty 0.2-1 amd64
  Pd-objects for simple matrix operations

pd-moonlib/trusty 0.2-2 amd64
  library of Pd objects related to GUI control

phasex/trusty 0.14.97-2 amd64
  Phase Harmonic Advanced Synthesis EXperiment

psychtoolbox-3-common/trusty 3.0.11.20131230.dfsg1-1build1 all
  toolbox for vision research -- arch/interpreter independent part

psychtoolbox-3-dbg/trusty 3.0.11.20131230.dfsg1-1build1 amd64
  toolbox for vision research -- debug symbols for binaries

psychtoolbox-3-lib/trusty 3.0.11.20131230.dfsg1-1build1 amd64
  toolbox for vision research -- arch-specific parts

python-mathgl/trusty 2.1.3.1-4ubuntu3 amd64
  library for scientific graphs (Python module)

python-nlopt/trusty 2.4.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1 amd64
  nonlinear optimization library -- Python bindings

python-pyfann/trusty 2.1.0~beta~dfsg-8ubuntu1 amd64
  Python bindings for FANN

python-pyfann-dbg/trusty 2.1.0~beta~dfsg-8ubuntu1 amd64
  Debugging symbols for FANN Python wrapper

qtoctave/trusty 0.10.1-4 amd64
  Qt front-end to Octave

sdpam/trusty 7.3.9+dfsg-1build1 amd64
  Matlab/Octave interface of SDPA

shogun-cmdline-static/trusty 3.1.1-1 amd64
  Large Scale Machine Learning Toolbox

shogun-doc-cn/trusty 3.1.1-1 all
  Large Scale Machine Learning Toolbox

shogun-doc-en/trusty 3.1.1-1 all
  Large Scale Machine Learning Toolbox

src2tex/trusty 2.12h-8ubuntu1 amd64
  A converter from source program files to TeX format files

texlive-pictures/trusty 2013.20140215-1 all
  TeX Live: Graphics, pictures, diagrams

udav/trusty 2.1.3.1-4ubuntu3 amd64
  library for scientific graphs (window interface)
```

Command 3 : apt show octave

```
Package: octave
Priority: extra
Section: universe/math
Installed-Size: 3,196 kB
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Octave Group <pkg-octave-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Version: 3.8.1-1ubuntu1
Replaces: octave-java, octave3.2
Depends: libamd2.3.1, libarpack2 (>= 2.1), libblas3 | libblas.so.3, libc6 (>= 2.14), libccolamd2.8.0, libcholmod2.1.2, libcolamd2.8.0, libcxsparse3.1.2, libfftw3-double3, libfftw3-single3, libfltk-gl1.3 (>= 1.3.0), libfltk1.3 (>= 1.3.1), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1, libglpk36 (>= 4.51), libglu1-mesa | libglu1, libgraphicsmagick++3, libgraphicsmagick3 (>= 1.3.5), liboctave2 (= 3.8.1-1ubuntu1), libqhull6, libqscintilla2-11, libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3), libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1), libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0), libstdc++6 (>= 4.6), libx11-6, texinfo, octave-common (= 3.8.1-1ubuntu1), default-jre-headless
Recommends: gnuplot-x11 | gnuplot-qt, libatlas3-base | libopenblas-base, pstoedit
Suggests: octave-info, octave-doc, octave-htmldoc
Conflicts: octave-java, octave3.2
Breaks: dynare (<= 4.4.1-1), libsbml5-octave (<= 5.8.0-2), octave-audio (<= 1.1.4-4), octave-biosig (<= 1.3.0-2), octave-communications (<= 1.2.0-1), octave-control (<= 2.6.2-1), octave-econometrics (<= 1:1.1.1-2), octave-gdf (<= 0.1.2-2), octave-general (<= 1.3.2-2), octave-geometry (<= 1.7.0-1), octave-gmt (<= 4.5.11-1), octave-gsl (<= 1.0.8-5), octave-image (<= 2.0.0-3), octave-io (<< 1.3), octave-java (<= 1.2.9-2), octave-lhapdf (<= 5.9.1-3), octave-linear-algebra (<= 2.2.0-1), octave-miscellaneous (<= 1.2.0-2), octave-mpi (<= 1.1.1-1), octave-nan (<= 2.5.9-1), octave-nlopt (<= 2.4.1+dfsg-1), octave-nurbs (<= 1.3.7-1), octave-ocs (<= 0.1.3-1), octave-octcdf (<= 1.1.6-1), octave-octgpr (<= 1.2.0-3), octave-odepkg (<= 0.8.4-1), octave-openmpi-ext (<= 1.1.1-1), octave-optim (<= 1.2.2-2), octave-optiminterp (<= 0.3.4-1), octave-parallel (<= 2.2.0-1), octave-pfstools (<= 1.8.5-1), octave-plplot (<= 5.9.9-5), octave-psychtoolbox-3 (<= 3.0.11.20131230.dfsg1-1), octave-quaternion (<= 2.2.0-1), octave-secs2d (<= 0.0.8-4), octave-signal (<= 1.2.2-1), octave-sockets (<= 1.0.8-1), octave-specfun (<= 1.1.0-1), octave-strings (<= 1.1.0-1), octave-struct (<= 1.0.10-1), octave-sundials (<= 2.5.0-3), octave-symbolic (<= 1.1.0-2), octave-tsa (<= 4.2.7-1), octave-vlfeat (<= 0.9.17+dfsg0-6), sdpam (<= 7.3.9+dfsg-1)
Download-Size: 864 kB
Homepage: http://www.octave.org/
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Description: GNU Octave language for numerical computations
 Octave is a (mostly Matlab (R) compatible) high-level language, primarily
 intended for numerical computations. It provides a convenient command-line
 interface for solving linear and nonlinear problems numerically.
 .
 Octave can be dynamically extended with user-supplied C++ files.
```

Thanks!

Comment: could you add the initial apt command you used to trigger the installation? This would let us know what packages you tried to install in detail (just to avoid errors)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

First, try to back-track and remove whatever you've put onto the system to prevent possible conflicts when reinstalling. The accepted answer in the post you linked to yourself has very good information there on how to do that, and particularly what to not do.

When installing software in Ubuntu, a user should always try the easiest solution first: search in the package repositories with 
`$ apt search octave` in this case. You will see that there are a lot of related packages. Of course you are curious about whether this will be up-to-date enough for your purposes, so you use `$ apt show octave` which returns:

```
Package: octave
Version: 4.0.0-3ubuntu9     <-- The important part, v4.0.0 is pretty new, you get the gui
Priority: extra
Section: universe/math
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Octave Group <pkg-octave-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 4,817 kB
Depends: (blah blah blah)
Suggests: octave-info, octave-doc, octave-htmldoc
Conflicts: octave-java
Breaks: (blah blah blah)
Replaces: octave-java
Homepage: http://www.octave.org/
Download-Size: 1,474 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://mirror.its.sfu.ca/mirror/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Description: GNU Octave language for numerical computations
 Octave is a (mostly Matlab (R) compatible) high-level language, primarily
 intended for numerical computations. It provides a convenient command-line
 interface for solving linear and nonlinear problems numerically.
 .
 Octave can be dynamically extended with user-supplied C++ files.
```

So, with a v4 Octave available in the repositories, it's pretty reasonable to use a simple `$ sudo apt install octave` and let the Ubuntu/Debian packaging community solve all the hard problems for you.

---

Regarding uninstallation, searching through the files in `octave-3.8.0/`, namely `README` and `INSTALL`, there are some helpful tips:

```
Basic Installation
==================

(blah blah blah)

 7. Often, you can also type `make uninstall' to remove the installed
     files again.  In practice, not all packages have tested that
     uninstallation works correctly, even though it is required by the
     GNU Coding Standards.
```

After running `$ make uninstall` or `$ sudo make uninstall` (which will be necessary if you used `sudo` to install the compiled program before), you should be good to try and get your package state in good order with:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt install -f
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
$ sudo ldconfig
```

These above commands are safe to use, and helpful for correcting weird state of your package installs. After that, for installing `octave`, go with:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt install octave
```

Comment: Thanks for answers, but you say back track, how can i do that?

Comment: I have updated my question with output of those commands. I am trying to do a manual install. I do not want to remove any existing packages as they may be being used by other software.

Comment: My mistake: I make the assumption that people who are new would install the newest LTS. This is not required for a working install of `octave`, 14.04 will work also, just with an older version (3.8, which coincidentally is the same version that you had tried to download and compile yourself).

I am reading through the files in the source code tarball for v3.8 to see about instructions for uninstallation.