# Uninstalling octave from ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, software-uninstall, octave

I had downloaded the source code of GNU octave and had installed it using `make install`. However, the installation had some error, due to which it could not open the GUI on launching octave.

For this reason I wanted to un-install the package.

For un-installing, I opened the software center. There in installed packages list, I could see GNU octave enlisted. On clicking on remove button, nothing happens.

Hence I tried to uninstall the package from command prompt using

```
sudo apt-get remove octave 
sudo apt-get autoremove octave
```

Still octave did not disappear from `/usr/local/bin` folder. So, I manually deleted it using:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/octave
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/octave
```

Now when I again go back to software center, GNU octave is still enlisted as installed software.

I want to install it again, properly. For which I want to completely remove the previous installation.

My questions are:

1. What else is required to completely remove octave
2. How to correctly install it so that I can use its GUI efficiently

Note: the octave version is 4.0.1
Ubuntu version - 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 3):

Gauri. I just successfully uninstalled Octave from my ubuntu 16.04 according to the solutions at http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/xenial/universe/o/octave/uninstall/index.html.

I saw something is wrong in your code `sudo apt-get autoremove octave`. The right way should be `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove octave`. Perhaps you could try it out and see if my suggestion works. Good luck!

Comment: I also want to share with you how I installed Octave-4.0.2 after I uninstalled the previous version. First line: wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-4.0.2.tar.gz   Second line: tar xf octave-4.0.2.tar.gz  Third line: sudo apt-get build-dep octave  Fourth line:  cd octave-4.0.2/   Fifth line: ./configure   Sixth line: sudo apt-get install octave   Seventh line: sudo octave # The seventh line is to run octave in your computer.  This approach works for me. Hope it works right on your computer.

Comment: Please [edit] your comment into into the post to make it easier to find.

Comment: Hi @Liz, your Sixth line will install Octave from Ubuntu repository, not from the source, because it used apt-get. You should run `make` and  `make install` after `configure`.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Octave through the `./configure && make && sudo make install` process from source code, you can uninstall by entering the build directory where you ran `sudo make install`, and running this command:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

EDIT: This is true as of version 3.8.0 because it has an `uninstall` rule in its `Makefile`. Please check if your version has the same, or similar, rule.

In order to determine whether such a rule exists, open up the `Makefile` of the version of Octave source code you have downloaded, and look for the string `uninstall:`. If so, it means you have an uninstall rule, and that you can run `make uninstall`.

[This Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/685842/225694) is the source of this information